# How do I make to read from folder and save in another folder in Python

Tags: python, directory, nltk, tokenize

This code works but I have to call all the files one by one, I need to call only the folder where the files are and to save the results in another folder.
I am not figuring out :( Can anybody help me, I'm new in Python.  Thank you I appreciate :)

```py
import re
import string
import sys

frequency = {}
sys.stdin = open('C:/Users/Desktop/app/data/sources/books/test.txt', 'r')
sys.stdout =open('C:/Users/Desktop/app/data/fre/news/test.txt', 'w')

text_string = sys.stdin.read()

match_pattern = re.findall(r'([-][\w]+)', text_string)

for word in match_pattern:
    count = frequency.get(word,0)
    frequency[word] = count + 1

frequency_list = frequency.keys()

for word in frequency_list:
    print (word, frequency[word])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```py
import glob
import os

books = glob.glob("C:/Users/Desktop/app/data/sources/books/*.txt")

# now you have a list of all .txt files in that directory.

def writer(text_string, output_file):

    """A function to write out items from an input text string"""

    frequency = {}

    match_pattern = re.findall(r'([-][\w]+)', text_string)

    for word in match_pattern:
        count = frequency.get(word,0)
        frequency[word] = count + 1

    frequency_list = frequency.keys()

    for word in frequency_list:
        print(word, frequency[word], file=open(output_file, "a"))

# now you have a function that essentially does the procedure you already know works

for book in books:

    book_name = os.path.split(book)[-1]  # get <filename>.txt from the path

    # context manager will close the stream when you're done
    with open(book, "r") as file:  
        
        text_string = file.read()

        output_file = "C:/Users/Desktop/app/data/fre/news/" + book_name

        writer(text_string, output_file)
```

This code will iterate through the `.txt` files in the directory you were reading from.

I encapsulated your working code in a function (somewhat reformatted for clarity, you can specify where to print to directly from the `print` function), so as you iterate through the files you can read them in and drop them through the working code.

Comment: thank you for a faster reply, I tried this code I'm having this error 'str' object has no attribute 'write' :(

Comment: oh, apologies, should be `open(output_file, "w")` after all. I have edited it.

Comment: can you please edit in the comment in code because I am not figuring out :( Thank you :) very  much

Comment: Yes, it's working now, but it's not showing my results :( The meaning is to read from the folder to process the tokenization and to save the files in another folder

Comment: Do you want separate files for each input file? At the moment it's putting everything into C:/Users/Desktop/app/data/fre/news/test.txt ...

I have made an edit to the answer to write to separate files.

Comment: Yes exactly, thank you; but now I'm having can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to strand is not saving in the output folder

Comment: I had a typo, left [-1] off of `os.path.split(book)[-1]` - fixed.

Comment: Great, just now I'm having a problem with the results of files is not showing all lines only one line :( example. the file list: has now-then; extra-time; show-time in the output folder it shows only the -then

Comment: Ah! Okay, I learned something new. It's `open(output_file, "a")` if you want output to be appended to an existing file, otherwise it just overwrites it. Fixed.

Comment: YESSS it's working OMG you are amazing thank you very much I appreciate your help :) God bless you!